# How to check if CLI defined MACRO (-DMACRO=) is defined or not

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

How to check if a macro is defined or not, when the definition is provided in compile time.

I've Makefile which resolves and passes this string ("`-DMACRO_TEST=${DEFINED}`") when compiling sample C file.
The variable DEFINED may or may not have a value (0 or non-zero). 
I wanted to know how to check if the `MACRO_TEST` is defined or not, when variable DEFINED itself doesn't have any value. This is similar to passing "-DMACRO_TEST=" when compiling the C file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef MACRO_TEST
char msg[] = "MACRO_TEST is defined";
#else
char msg[] = "MACRO_TEST is NOT-defined";
#endif

int main ()
{
    printf("msg = %s\n", msg);
    return 0;
}
```

Command line output

```
$ gcc tmp.c -DMACRO_TEST=0
$ ./a.out
msg = MACRO_TEST is defined
$ gcc tmp.c -DMACRO_TEST=
$ ./a.out
msg = MACRO_TEST is defined
```

when compiling in 2nd case, I was expecting it would return

```
msg = MACRO_TEST is NOT-defined
```

Comment: It is defined, but with the value "empty", because the make replaces any missing variables with empty. I am actually not sure if the compiler will then define it as empty, or as the default, 1, when no assignment is given. You could explore this in the C code using the expression  `MACRO_TEST+0`

Comment: There is a duplicate question which asked how to differentiate when a macro is unset, empty, zero or anything else. But I can't find it.

Comment: @GemTaylor, It works for me. However, before i tired I was thinking it will give compile time error as `+` op needs 2 args and when MACRO_TEST is set to "empty". How will this work.

Answer (score 2):

Some common cases for testing macros:

```
#ifdef MACRO_TEST
  // MACRO_TEST is defined, whatever its content, even empty
  // for example:
  //   -DMACRO_TEST
  //   -DMACRO_TEST=
  //   -DMACRO_TEST=0
  //   -DMACRO_TEST=1
  //   -DMACRO_TEST=abcd
#else
  // MACRO_TEST is not defined, not even with an empty content
#endif

#if MACRO_TEST // it must not be defined as empty (-DMACRO_TEST= --> error)
  // MACRO_TEST has a non-zero integer value
  // for example:
  //   -DMACRO_TEST
  //   -DMACRO_TEST=1    -- equivalent to -DMACRO_TEST
  //   -DMACRO_TEST=23
#else
  // MACRO_TEST has a zero integer value
  // for example:
  //   (not defined at all, then considered as zero)
  //   -DMACRO_TEST=0
  //   -DMACRO_TEST=what
#endif
```

Comment: Note that the `#if MACRO_TEST` will work if `MACRO_TEST` is not defined at all; the preprocessor will convert the name to `0` and evaluate the condition appropriately.  If `MACRO_TEST` is defined, it must not be empty (so `-DMACRO_TEST` is OK; `-DMACRO_TEST=` is not), and it must be defined as a numeric value or an identifier; it should not be a string `-DMACRO_TEST='"string"'` (beware the single and double quotes in that!).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Thank you for the clarification. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Note that if there's a macro `-Dwhat=1`, then the `-DMACRO_TEST=what` will expand the `what` to `1`, etc.  I'm not sure whether that needs to be called out in the answer (maybe this comment suffices).  'Tis tricky stuff — the preprocessor leads to intricate problems on occasion.

Answer (score 2):

If you omit any option `-DMACRO_TEST` or explicitly add `-UMACRO_TEST` (= undefine macro) in the `gcc` command line, the macro will not be defined. In this case the preprocessor directive `#ifdef MACRO_TEST` will be FALSE, and you will get

```
char msg[] = "MACRO_TEST is NOT-defined";
```

in the `#else` branch.

(Assuming you don't define this macro in the code.)

Comment: I know i've mentioned CLI in summary. but the end compilation process is done by using Makefile, which i don't want to update.

Comment: @SheetalT Then show the Makefile (or the file from which it was generated) in your question. How do you get the macro definition into your Makefile? What are the possible macro definitions you want to distinguish.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `#if xxx`. Undefined `xxx` is treated as zero by the preprocessor.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if MACRO_TEST
char msg[] = "MACRO_TEST is defined";
#else
char msg[] = "MACRO_TEST is NOT-defined";
#endif

int main ()
{
    printf("msg = %s\n", msg);
    return 0;
}
```

---

And, you don't have to supply a value on the commandline, just`-Dxxx` is sufficient, and the compiler/preprocessor will assume `1`:

```
cc -Wall -DMACRO_TEST defined.c
```

---

UPDATE. All four cases:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if MACRO_TEST
char msg[] = "MACRO_TEST is defined and non-zero";
#else
char msg[] = "MACRO_TEST is NOT-defined or zero";
#endif

int main (int argc, char**argv)
{
    printf("%s: msg = %s\n", argv[0], msg);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#!bin/sh

cc -Wall defined.c -o x
cc -Wall -DMACRO_TEST defined.c -o xd
cc -Wall -DMACRO_TEST=0 defined.c -o xd0
cc -Wall -DMACRO_TEST=1 defined.c -o xd1

./x
./xd
./xd0
./xd1

rm x xd xd0 xd1
```

---

result:

---

```
./x: msg = MACRO_TEST is NOT-defined or zero
./xd: msg = MACRO_TEST is defined and non-zero
./xd0: msg = MACRO_TEST is NOT-defined or zero
./xd1: msg = MACRO_TEST is defined and non-zero
```

Comment: This is almost right, but if he wants 0 to be a valid value, a multi-part test should work: `#if defined(MACRO_TEST) && MACRO_TEST != ""` will accept all definitions except empty string (just as an example).

Comment: No,it is completely right, and it avoids the three-valued-logic. I even tested it!

Comment: The string comparison is dubious, @GaryO.

Comment: He wants a value of 0 to trigger his "is defined" branch. Using `#if MACRO_TEST` alone will cause a value of 0 to go into his "NOT-defined" branch.

Comment: IMHO the  OP just wants to  have only two cases. Ok, To prove mypoint, I'll update the answer. ...